# MVVM and WPF - how to combine sources for a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am fairly new to WPF/MVVM but I have read through a lot of tutorials and done some small projects so have gained an elementary understanding.

My problem:

I have a Model class which holds a collection of data. My main View must display several of Models' data on a DataGrid. My current approach is making a DataGrid in the Model's View by defining a Datatemplate with a DataGrid whose ItemsSource is the Model's Collection.

This approach sort of works but it creates a Datagrid for each Model. Does anyone know of a good way to have only a single DataGrid?

Comment: please show what you´ve tried so far...

Answer (score 1):

If the view should display a single grid you might want to make a ViewModel with a single collection and fill the collection from several Model collections.

That is what the ViewModel is for.

Comment: This seems promising. So the view model contains the references to all of the models' collections. Then the problem becomes: how to fill a datagrid with each column being bound to a different collection.

Comment: No, aggregate the models in the collections into a single collection in the viewmodel.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. So the model has a collection of Data. In my version, the view model has a collection of models. Are you saying to put all of the data in a single collection in the viewmodel? That is the only way I can see being able to use a Datagrid effectively.

Comment: Correct. The translation between view and model is the responsibility of the viewmodel. In many cases I do NOT use the model in the view because that would create a dependency which violates the MVVM pattern.